# Obj models with material transparency issues

Tags: rendering, import, transparency, normals, obj

I am working with a couple .obj formatted models that i downloaded from adobe stock. They both have identical transparency issues. I can't tell if this is related to issues with the materials, or this is something to do with with mesh. Any and all help with this is greatly appreciated.

I have looked at backface culling, and alpha transparency settings on the material node editor, also the normal face orientation shows every thing facing the correct way.

I attached a screen shot and a blend file as well

[image: screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Hello I can't see any link to the blend file

Comment: sorry having some issues attaching it.

Comment: you can upload here (and once done, copy paste the link): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: thanks @moonboots it took me a minute to figure out the file upload, first time posting here.

Comment: Alpha blend settings are not in the material node editor. They’re in the material properties tab in the properties editor.

Comment: I'm not sure what you checked, but the blend mode, the backface culling, and the face orientations are all wrong and need to be fixed, as well as the alpha and emissive maps. OBJ materials are almost always wrong and require manual clean up after import.

Comment: thank you all for the advice. this is the first time dealing with this issue. and im relatively new to blender. I appreciate the support.

Comment: i agree with @scurest. You can get results "somehow" ( [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFBq3.png) but for me the textures look messed up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch back to *Opaque* in the *Material > Viewport Display > Settings > Blend Mode*

Comment: thank you! that did resovle one of the issues. Im realizing that a lot of issues are present with this model.

Comment: also maybe in the Object Data panel > Geometry Data, click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data

Comment: thanks! i'll check that as well

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problems with assets from adobe stock and what fixed it for me was switching the render engine from Eevee to Cycles.